Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Angular 13
Getting this reference error after running the project (Check the link)
While debugging it is pointing to this particular function (Check the link)
I have tried removing the require function but still getting the same issue (Check the link)
I am trying to replace the require function and instead using an alternative which is directly importing the google-lib number so to remove the reference error. But it is not working.
